# mvn sonar:sonar do not use <libraries> in pom.xml

Tags: maven, libraries, sonarqube, hudson-plugins

i've got a problem with an sonar analysis trought maven.
in my pom.xml i define a tag  under 
my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" >
 <modelVersion 4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
 <artifactId>android-project</artifactId>
 <name>android project</name>
 <version>2.3.${HUDSON_SVN_REVISION}</version>
 <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <source>1.5</source>
              <target>1.5</target>
              <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
              </excludes>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <properties>
   <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>false</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
   <libraries>libs/android.jar</libraries>      
  </properties>
</project>
```

I run maven in hudson with sonar plugin, the build is succesfull but i have some warning in the output log of hudson:

```
[INFO]  Findbugs output report: C:\hudson\jobs\test_sonar_pdf\workspace\target\sonar\findbugs-result.xml
The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
  android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider
  android.os.AsyncTask
  android.app.Activity
  ...
```

But i'm sure that the android.jar is under libs folder. 
Perhaps there is a syntax problem?
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to you Fabrice, ly pom.xml file. I hope could help someone else

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
<artifactId>android-project</artifactId>
<name>android project</name>
<!-- Dans hudson, dans action a la suite du build, dans la partie sonar, dans propriete additionelles, ajouter
 -DHUDSON_SVN_REVISION=${SVN_REVISION} -->
<version>2.3.${HUDSON_SVN_REVISION}</version>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>   
   <groupId>deps</groupId>
   <artifactId>dep1</artifactId>
   <version>0.1</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/edtftpj.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>deps</groupId>
    <artifactId>dep2</artifactId>
    <version>0.2</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>C:\android\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-7\android.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <source>1.5</source>
              <target>1.5</target>
               <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
              </excludes>

          </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
 <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>false</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>       
</properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

The  tag is only used for the Ant task or the Simple Java Runner.

With Maven, you have to define your dependencies using the standard Maven  section of the POM (see http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies).